# C dynamic linking to shared libs suppressing/handling "cannot open shared object file" fatal error, and continue linking

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ld, dlsym

I want to link to a shared lib in C. (on Linux)

I want to suppress or handle the:

**"error while loading shared libraries: libxxxx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"**

and continue loading linking to next lib that might resolve the left unresolved symbols.

I guess gcc/ld/dlsym options should be used but can not manage to understand how...

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Don't link against the .so at build time. Instead, manually perform your own dlopen() / dlsym(). When you link against it at build time, the dynamic linker has expectations which you cannot change.

Comment: that is what dynamic linking is all about.

Comment: using dlopen/dlsym means knowing the exact ".so" filename to open. but one can not know in advance which ".so" filename will be used in the target machine. I guess it is better to dynamically link to shared lib via gcc/ld dynamic linking options, dont you think?

Comment: If you're passing anything regarding the library to the compiler/linker, you're not really doing a dynamic link; you're linking a small static component that will be seen by the loader at run time, and require the expected library to be found and loaded. This is what you want for standard libraries that your app cannot run without. (If you have optional libraries, you want a true dynamic link/load of them... you won't have specified anything to the compiler/ld though).

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting this error, you are linking to a shared library that does not exist (or at least does not exist on the library path) on the system doing the linking.

You cannot link to shared libraries that don't exist; if there are other libraries that might (hopefully will) resolve the symbols that remain to be linked, then just remove the link to the non-existent shared library.

If what you are trying to do is make it link to a shared library only if that library is there, the appropriate course of action is to open the library in the code using `dlopen()`, and not put it on the link line.

Comment: Also, you'll need to `dlsym` the result of `dlopen`

Comment: **how can I use dlopen if I don't know the exact ".so" filename on every machine? what about versions changes? is there a way to use SONAME with dlopen? does dlopen lookup similar filenames when exact filename isn't found?**

Comment: Im trying to dynamically link to libncursesw and fallback to libncurses if libncursesw isn't found. I could use dlopen to try and open each libncursesw.so file ever made though :)

Comment: and another problem is that as @BasileStarynkevitch says I will have to dlsym every symbol in ncurses (functions and globals?)

Comment: about the former comment:   it says in the manual that "RTLD_NOW, meaning resolve all undefined symbols before dlopen returns, and fail if this cannot be done". So does that mean that after dlopening with RTLD_NOW no dlsym is needed because all undefined symbols are resolved?

Comment: You `dlopen` a file like `libncurses.so.5`, the `5` specifying the API version. It will then search the library path, and find a file with that name, which would normally normally be a symlink to `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5.9` or whatever.

Comment: What you want to do is *almost* like using weak symbols. However, I believe the dynamic linker will always error if it can't find a .so at all, whether or not you have a wrapper around the whole lot making all the symbols weak. So I think you are stuck with `dlsym` (and you could write an autogenerated wrapper for that). Out of interest, why not just static link in `libcursesnw`?